# Title page Errors

Tags: latex

```
% Thesis master document
 \documentclass[final,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
  \textheight =24.2 cm 
 \textwidth =15 cm 
 \topmargin =-15mm

 \usepackage[round]{natbib}

 \usepackage{amssymb}

 \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage {mathrsfs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}

\def\hang{\hangindent\parindent}
\def\rf{\par\noindent\hang}

 \newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{result}{Result}


 \begin{document}

 \baselineskip = 18pt
 
 \pagestyle{plain}
 
 \frontmatter
 
 \include{Title}

 
 

 \maketitle
 \tableofcontents
 \listoftables
 %\listoffigures
 \include{Introduction}
 
 \mainmatter
 
 \include{Chapter1}
 \include{Chapter2}
 \include{Chapter3}
 \include{Chapter4}
 \include{Conclusion}
 %\include{Appendix}
 
 \backmatter
 
 \include{Bibliography}
 
 \end{document}
```

I've got the above code in my masterfile as part of my thesis due today. it has been executing properly until now. I accidently deleted the \maketitle command but when I put it back, it won't just execute. I get the error attached. I'm not sure if I placed it in wrongly this time. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Is your `Master.pdf` file maybe still open in adobe reader?

Comment: Ooh yes. Thank you. That was the fix. It was opened in adobe reader.

Comment: :) Good luck with handing in your thesis!